# Some pods are not working and showing in the project

Tags: cocoapods, backendless

I am working on starting up a project that uses [Backendless](https://backendless.com) and am following the [quick start guide](https://backendless.com/mobile-developers/quick-start-guide-for-ios/) that uses CocoaPods to install it.

Installing the pods went fine, but I can't use Backendless. I get a 'No such module` error. The other pod works fine.

Here is my `Podfile`:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Chatter' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Chatter
  pod 'Napalm', :git => 'https://github.com/Napalm-Framework/Napalm.git'
  pod 'Backendless'
end
```

A few things to note:

- Backendless is written in Obj-C
- Backendless does not install as a framework and the other pod does.
- Backendless never shows as part of  the build process.

Comment: Just a thought - maybe try `pod 'Backendless', :git => https://github.com/Backendless/iOS-SDK.git` ? Though the `.podspec` file is not in a root, but in `Pods` directory.

Comment: What is the version of XCode you use?

Comment: @MarkPiller, Xcode 8.0 beta 1.

Comment: @Scadge, I got a `Unable to find a specification for 'Backendless'.` error when I do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still not sure why using the pods wasn't working, but I found some instructions [here](https://backendless.com/documentation/data/ios/data_setup.htm) on how to install Backendless manually. Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

You should add in your bridging header a line:

## include Backendless.h

Also you could investigate this topic:
http://support.backendless.com/topic/cant-get-ios-sdk-working-after-xcode-8-update

Comment: One problem. I don't have a bridge-header.